# Data Tables for different columns

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, datatable

I need to read a csv data and copy each column (i have only two of them) into two different Data Tables and convert them to arrays. So at the end i need two arrays so that in array1 there are the lines of column1 and in array2 there are the lines of column2. How to do that? Do I even need Data Tables?

Edit: I tried this but get a "OutofBound" Exception

```
DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
csvData.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
csvData.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(double));

string dir = @"C:\Main\test.csv"; 

DataRow dr = csvData.NewRow();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dir))
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] strRow = line.Split(',');

        dr["Date"] = strRow[0];
        dr["Value"] = strRow[1];

        csvData.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

I tried something different (should work):

```
var date = new List<String>();
var value = new List<String>();

string dir = @"C:\Main\test.csv";

using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dir))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       var fields = line.Split(new Char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
       date.Add(fields[0]);
       if (fields.Length > 1)
           value.Add(fields[1]);
    }
}
string[] _date = date.ToArray();
string[] _value = value.ToArray();
```

Now I want to bind the Arrays to a chart but when I try this:

```
chart1.Series["Forecast"].Points.DataBindXY("_date","_value");
chart1.Series["Forecast"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
```

I get a System.Argument.Exception
and it tells me that Y-Values can only be bind to the string object

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: `StreamReader` is a good place to start from

Comment: If you need to read a csv file you should pick [Lumenworks CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader). With that you can quite simply iterate over the values of each column and write them to individual lists or arrays.

Comment: The exception you get could be an indication that there's at least one line in the file that does not contain two comma separated columns. See my answer for a fix/check.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a `DataTable`. You can try something like this:

```
// read all lines from file
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

// Create lists for first and second column
List<string> cols1 = new List<string>();
List<string> cols2 = new List<string>();

// Fill lists. This throws an exception if there's a line with only one column
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split(',');

    // Make sure that each line really contains at least two columns!
    if (parts.Length < 2)
        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("The following line contains only one column: '{0}'", line));

    cols1.Add(parts[0]);
    cold2.Add(parts[1]);
}

// Create arrays from lists
string[] colArray1 = cols1.ToArray();
string[] colArray2 = cols2.ToArray();
```

Of course, all of this could probably be done in less lines using LINQ, but this code is easier to understand.

---

EDIT: The code you posted fails to create a row per line in the file. It only creates a single line in the `DataTable` and modifies it for every line in the file. You need to use my code or put that line inside the loop like this:

```
DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
csvData.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
csvData.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(double));

string dir = @"C:\Main\test.csv"; 

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dir))
{
      string line = string.Empty;
      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         DataRow dr = csvData.NewRow();
         string[] strRow = line.Split(',');

         dr["Date"] = strRow[0];
         dr["Value"] = strRow[1];

         csvData.Rows.Add(dr);
      }
}
```

---

EDIT 2: The exception you get could be a hint that there's at least one line that does not contain two columns. You could easily check this by modifying your code as follows:

```
string[] strRow = line.Split(',');
if (strRow.Length < 2)
    throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("The following line contains only one column: '{0}'", line));
```

You should now get a different exception saying which line causes the error.

Comment: Now I get a "IndexOutOfRangeException"

Comment: In which line, please? And using my code or your modified code? If using my original code, as I said, this could be caused by one line in the CSV file that does *not* contain two comma-separated columns, but only one value.

Comment: I modified my code to also throw an `ArgumentException` when an invalid line is found.